# Proper method for a try, catch, and finally for Scanner and BufferedReader

Tags: java, try-catch, ioexception

Trying to understand the best and most efficient way for a try-catch-finally for both the Scanner and BufferedReader in my main method.  Should there be two different catches or combine them into one?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //open file input stream
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("DATABASE.txt"));

        //read file line by line
        String line = null;
        Scanner scan = null;

        BST tree = new BST();
        line = reader.readLine();

        while(line != null) {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            scan = new Scanner(line);
            scan.useDelimiter(",");

            while(scan.hasNext()){
                emp.setEmployeeID(Integer.parseInt(scan.next()));
                emp.setFirstName(scan.next());
                emp.setLastName(scan.next());
                emp.setSalary(Double.parseDouble(scan.next()));
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            tree.insert(emp);
        }
        reader.close();
        tree.inOrder();
        //System.out.println(empList);
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single catch block should be sufficient. You can add a finally block that will close the reader and scanner instances (if they are non null). This way, they will be closed regardless if the try block finishes normally or an exception is thrown. The null checks should be added because the try block might not reach the initialization of both objects, as an exception might occur.

Comment: Saying that, should I remove the Scanner object outside the try statement and just keep the instantiated block of code inside?

Comment: if you keep the scanner and reader objects declared in the try block, you won't be able to use them in the finally block. So you have to declare them before the try block, but you should keep the initialization inside the try block, so the exception can be caught

Answer (score 0):

Declared `Scanner scan = null` and `BufferedReader reader = null;` outside of the try-catch-finally block of code and initialized them inside the try block.  The exception gets caught and they both reach the finally block.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    //open file input stream
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("DATABASE.txt"));

        //read file line by line
        String line = null;
        Scanner scan = null;

        BST tree = new BST();
        line = reader.readLine();
        scan = new Scanner(line);
        while (line != null) {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            scan.useDelimiter(",");

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                emp.setEmployeeID(Integer.parseInt(scan.next()));
                emp.setFirstName(scan.next());
                emp.setLastName(scan.next());
                emp.setSalary(Double.parseDouble(scan.next()));
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            tree.insert(emp);
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use both `BufferedReader` and `Scanner`. One `Scanner` is enough:

```
public static BST readFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        scan.useLocale(Locale.US);  // mandatory for read double values

        BST bst = new BST();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setEmployeeID(scan.nextInt());
            employee.setFirstName(scan.next());
            employee.setLastName(scan.next());
            employee.setSalary(scan.nextDouble());
            bst.insert(employee);
        }

        bst.inOrder();
        return bst;
    }
}
```